# Create excel file - compilation error

Tags: java, excel, compilation, compiler-errors, apache-poi

I tried below code but no good, I am unable to create excel document, open and close it.

```
package tests;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;  
import org.apache.poi.xssf.util.*;  
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Xls_Reader  {


Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();  
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");

}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Default constructor can not handle exception type FileNotFoundException 
    thrown by implicit super constructor . Must define an explicit constructor.
```

Can someone help me understand the concept of creating excel file with POI API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These examples can help you to understand better

1. [Create Excel(.xlsx) document using Apache POI](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/poi/ApachePoiCreateXlsx.shtml)
2. [Read and write Excel file using Apache POI](http://openwritings.net/public/java/read-and-write-excel-file-using-apache-poi)

Answer (score 3):

This will not compile:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Xls_Reader  {

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
}
```

But this fixes the error:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Xls_Reader  {

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");

    public Xls_Reader() throws IOException {
    }
}
```

The stream is instantiated as the instance is being constructed.  If it fails, so will the construction.

---

BTW - this is 'Java 101' and has nothing to do with Apache POI.

Answer (score 3):

Either you declare a constructor at your subclass that explicitly throws FileNotFoundException:

```
public Xls_Reader() throws FileNotFoundException {...}
```

Or you surround the code in your base class with a try-catch block instead of throwing a FileNotFoundException exception:

```
    FileInputStream fileOut = null;
    try { 
          FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
          // do something
        } 
   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { ... } 
   finally {
        try 
        {
        // do something
            fileOut();
        } catch (IOException ex) {... }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for 'better exception handling'.  My example just 'throws the ticking bomb to the next fool'.  ;)